# Shopify: invite emails not sending to customers

Tags: shopify

From outside system built in PHP, I wrote this following to call API for create customer account:

```
 'customer' => 
array (
  'first_name' => $_POST['datalog']['firstName'],
  'last_name' => $_POST['datalog']['lastName'],
  'email' => $_POST['datalog']['email'],
  'verified_email'=> true,
  'password'=> $rand_pass,
  'password_confirmation' => $rand_pass,
  //'send_email_welcome' => true,
  'send_email_invite' => true,
),
```

Creation of customers are working successfully but they did not receive any invitation email. I have followed the Shopify Documentation : https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/customer

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Customer Invites API: https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/customer#send_invite